# Calling 'created' method inside Jest tests on Vue.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, mocking, jestjs

I'm testing my `Activity.vue` component on Vue.js with Jest.

My `Activity.vue` component calls the `initializeTable()` method inside `created()` in order to initialize my `tableRows` property.

The problem is, when I run my tests, Jest does not call 'created()' method and, for that reason, it does not initialize my `tableRows` property, then the test says that my `tableRows` property is equal to `[]` (original state).

How could I call `created()` method when I'm testing with Jest?

I've already tried to call it explicitly inside the test (i.e. `wrapper.vm.$created()`), but to no avail.

Would anyone know how to solve it?

I give my code below.

Thank you in advance.

**Activity.spec.js**

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Activity from '@/views/Activity.vue'
import api from '@/assets/js/api'

const expectedTableRows = [...]

const $t = () => {}

api.getActivity = jest.fn(
  () => Promise.resolve({
    data: [...]
  })
)

describe('Activity.vue', () => {
  it('renders vm.tableRows in created()', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Activity, {
      mocks: { $t }
    })
    // wrapper.vm.$created()
    expect(wrapper.vm.tableRows).toEqual(expectedTableRows)
  })
})
```

**Activity.vue**

```js
import api from '@/assets/js/api'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      tableRows: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.initializeTable()
  },
  methods: {
    initializeTable () {
      this.loading = true

      api.getActivity().then(response => {
        this.tableRows = response.data
      }).catch(error => {
        this.errorBackend = error
      }).finally(() => {
        this.loading = false
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1: Solution**

As Husam Ibrahim described, the function is asynchronous, because of that, I needed to refactor the test using the following [tips](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html#testing-asynchronous-behavior) and now I was able to fix it.

I give the correct code below:

```js
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises'    // <--

...

describe('Activity.vue', () => {
  it('renders wm.tableRows after created()', async () => {    // <--
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Activity, {
      mocks: { $t }
    })

    await flushPromises()    // <-- 

    expect(wrapper.vm.tableRows).toEqual(expectedTableRows)
  })
})
```

Comment: That assertion runs synchronously whereas the method makes an asynchronous call.

Comment: You are right. Thank you so much. God bless.